# getElementByID doesn't get filled

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to to manipulate an element depending if the user has already visited a page or not. Thereby I do that:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var index_da = Cookies.get('sw_home_visit') || 0;
    if (index_da < 1) {
        Cookies.set('sw_home_visit', '1', {
            expires: 365
        });
        document.getElementByID("cookietest").innerHTML = "Neu";
        console.log("Neu");
    } else {
        document.getElementByID("cookietest").innerHTML = "Alt";
        console.log("Alt");
    }
</script>
```

with

```
<p id="cookietest"></p>
```

And I get the correct things printed to the console, but my #cookietest-element doesn't get manipulated at all (it's empty initially and it keeps empty actually). The same thing happens if I try it with getElementsByClassName. What do I do wrong?

Comment: getElementsByClassName? try getElementById

Comment: "And I get the correct things printed to the console" — You do? Really? You should get an error telling you that `document.getElementByID` is not a function.

Comment: You are calling `getElementByID()`, notice capital **ID** there. The method is `getElementById()` (only capital I)

Comment: `What do I do wrong?` You are not reading your console errors or debugging your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById` and it should work :)